# setOnMouseEntered / Exited on ListView Cell

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to make a ListView in which each cell is composed of a Label and a Button. I want to make the Button appear when my mouse flies over the cell and disappear when it flies out. To do that I used the method setOnMouseEntered() on the ListCell object but the Button appears only for the first cell (the latest item added to the ObservableList)

My Custom ListCell class :

```
public class SubscribedTopicListCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private final Label lSubscribedTopic = new Label();
    private final Button btnUnsubscribe = new Button();
    private static final ImageView ivBtnGraphic = new ImageView(new Image("resources/images/cross.png"));

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setGraphic(null);
        if (!empty && item != null) {
            lSubscribedTopic.setText(item);
            btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(false);
            btnUnsubscribe.setGraphic(ivBtnGraphic);
            btnUnsubscribe.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
            btnUnsubscribe.setOnAction(e -> 
                MqttConnection.getInstance().unsubscribe(item)
            );
            this.setOnMouseEntered(e ->
                btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(true)
            );
            this.setOnMouseExited(e -> 
                btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(false)
            );
            GridPane listCellPane = new GridPane();
            listCellPane.add(lSubscribedTopic, 0, 0);
            listCellPane.add(btnUnsubscribe, 1, 0);
            ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col0.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
            ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col1.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
            col1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            listCellPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col0, col1);
            setGraphic(listCellPane);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it work for each cells ?

Comment: Why is the `ImageView` static?

Comment: I thought it would avoid the application to load the image each time a cell is created. It works fine when it's not static, but I don't understand why. I set the visibilty on the Button and not on the ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one cell can ever have a button, because you have made the `ImageView` static. `ImageView` is a [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), and each node can only appear once in the scene graph. By making the `ImageView` static, you try to force the same `ImageView` into the scene graph in multiple places. When you call `setGraphic(...)` on a button, the image view effectively gets removed from the previous button in order to fulfill the rule that it can only be used once in the scene graph. (I suspect all the buttons are really there, but only one has a graphic: since there is no text and no background, the others are completely invisible, probably with zero dimension.)

The fix is to make the `ImageView` an instance variable. Note that `Image` is **not** a node, and multiple `ImageView`s can share the same `Image`, so you can avoid multiple copies of the image data in memory by making the `Image` static.

Finally, while it won't really change the functionality, it doesn't really make sense to re-register the listeners every time `updateItem()` is called; you can do this just once in the constructor. Similarly for the layout:

```
public class SubscribedTopicListCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private final Label lSubscribedTopic = new Label();
    private final Button btnUnsubscribe = new Button();

    private static final Image image = new Image("resources/images/cross.png");

    private final ImageView ivBtnGraphic = new ImageView(image);

    private final GridPane listCellPane = new GridPane();

    public SubscribedTopicListCell() {
            btnUnsubscribe.setOnAction(e -> 
                MqttConnection.getInstance().unsubscribe(getItem())
            );
            this.setOnMouseEntered(e ->
                btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(true)
            );
            this.setOnMouseExited(e -> 
                btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(false)
            );
            listCellPane.add(lSubscribedTopic, 0, 0);
            listCellPane.add(btnUnsubscribe, 1, 0);
            ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col0.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
            ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col1.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
            col1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            listCellPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col0, col1);
            btnUnsubscribe.setVisible(false);
            btnUnsubscribe.setGraphic(ivBtnGraphic);
            btnUnsubscribe.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setGraphic(null);
        if (!empty && item != null) {
            lSubscribedTopic.setText(item);
            setGraphic(listCellPane);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I didn't know that a node can only appear once in the scene... Indeed the buttons were still there but were invisible.